# Unable to create a facetplot for each athlete in my dataset (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a tibble from which I want to create a facet plot for each unique skier.

```
`# A tibble: 6 x 16
     X1 kohort    dag   bib   run course           gruppe  inter1 inter2 inter3 inter4 inter5 inter6 finish median.straightgliding difference
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>                  <dbl>      <dbl>
1     0 kohort2     1     1     1 STRAIGHT-GLIDING BLOCKED   0.76   5.98   6.44   10.7   11.1   18.4   18.8                   18.8     -0.05 
2     1 kohort2     1     1     2 COURSE 3         BLOCKED   0.77   6.54   7.06   12.0   12.4   21.7   22.2                   18.8      3.33 
3     2 kohort2     1     1     3 COURSE 1         BLOCKED   0.76   6.13   6.59   11.0   11.4   19     19.4                   18.8      0.540
4     3 kohort2     1     1     4 COURSE 3         BLOCKED   0.77   6.44   6.94   11.7   12.1   21.4   21.8                   18.8      2.98 
5     4 kohort2     1     1     5 COURSE 2         BLOCKED   0.78   6.2    6.68   11.2   11.7   20.6   21.0                   18.8      2.19 
6     5 kohort2     1     1     6 COURSE 1         BLOCKED   0.76   6.1    6.56   10.9   11.3   19.0   19.3                   18.8      0.520``
```

The following code works for rendering the plot for each skier if the tibble has already been filtered:

```
bib7 <- read_csv("bib7.csv")

bib7$DAG_N = factor(bib7$DAG, levels=c('PRETEST','TRENING1','TRENING2','TRENING3', 'POSTTEST'))

bib7 <- ggplot(bib7, aes(run, finish, colour = course)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_grid(.~DAG_N) + # create a facet for each mountain range
  ylab("TID I SEKUND")

bib7 + 
  scale_x_continuous('RUNDENUMMER')
```

...but I need to rewrite the code for every bib. Thus, I thought it would be a better idea to use a for loop instead, as I would have done in Python.

```
for (bib in unique(df$bib)){
  df %>%
  filter(df == bib) %>%
  ggplot(df, aes(run, difference, colour = course)) + 
    geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_grid(.~DAG_N) + 
    ylab("Differanse fra median Straight-gliding (sek)") +
    scale_x_continuous('Runde')
}
```

But it throws me an error that I'm unable to debug: Error in UseMethod("filter_") :
no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'logical')". Can someone please help me

Comment: In `for` loop I think you were trying to do `df %>% filter(bib == bib)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the data into list of dataframes for each `bib` and plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

bib7 %>%
  mutate(DAG_N = factor(DAG, levels=c('PRETEST','TRENING1','TRENING2',
                                      'TRENING3', 'POSTTEST'))) %>%
  group_split(bib) %>%
  map(function(x) {
    ggplot(x, aes(run, difference, colour = course)) + 
        geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_grid(.~DAG_N) + 
        ylab("Differanse fra median Straight-gliding (sek)") +
        scale_x_continuous('Runde')
}) -> list_plot
```

`list_plot` would have list of plots. You can access each individual plot with `list_plot[[1]]`, `list_plot[[2]]` etc.

Comment: Cheers. Is this an assignment operator:  -> list_plot. I'm new to R but I have never seen it :)

Comment: Yes, `->` is an assignment operator similar to `<-`. Both `a <- 10` and `10 -> a` are the same.